# undefined value from html button value attribute

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom, js, template

I am iterating an array in template and on the button click I am trying to get the value of selected element but the value coming is undefined

```
<template>
    <template for:each={pages} for:item="page">
        <li key={page.name}>
            <button type="button" title="Duplicate" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" onclick={duplicatePage} data-value={page.index} data-id={page.index}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:copy" alternative-text="Copy" title="Copy" size="xx-small"></lightning-icon>
            </button>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" title="Delete" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" onclick={deletePage} data-value={page.index} data-id={page.index}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:delete" alternative-text="Delete" title="Delete" size="xx-small"></lightning-icon>
            </button>
        </li>
    </template>
</template>
```

JS File

```
deletePage(event){
    //console.log('index delete '+event.target.dataset.value);
    this.pages.splice(event.target.dataset.value, 1);
}
```

Comment: Exactly which value is undefined? The `dataset.value`? Please [edit] the question to answer this, but also to add the JavaScript that sets up the `pages` array, especially the `index`.

Comment: yes the dataset is undefined, I have tried value={page.index} also.

Comment: Could you please show us how `pages` is setted?

Comment: Could you please try using `event.currentTarget.dataset.value` instead of `event.target.dataset.value`?

Comment: @RubenDG thanks it is solved now

Comment: @MuskanAgarwal yes this has solved the issue :)